# Where to call Recover() when using ErrorBoundary with App.razor in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

## What I do

I use ErrorBoundary in App.brazor to display the error in a custom layout when exception occurs.
I am using the following code.

#### App.razor

```razor
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        // use ErrorBoundary in App.razor
        <ErrorBoundary>
            <ChildContent>
                ...
            </ChildContent>
            <ErrorContent>
                // using custom layout
                <LayoutView Layout="typeof(ErrorLayout)">
                    <Error500 Exception="@context" />
                </LayoutView>
            </ErrorContent>
        </ErrorBoundary>
    </Found>
    ...
</Router>
```

#### ErrorLayout.razor

```razor
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<PageTitle>BlazorApp2</PageTitle>

@Body
```

#### Error500.razor

```razor
<PageTitle>Server Error</PageTitle>

<h1>Server Error</h1>

<pre>@Exception?.ToString()</pre>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Exception? Exception { get; set; }
}
```

### Expected Behavior

Expected behavior. (Code sample BlazorApp1)

1. `Counter` link click -> Nagivat to `/counter`
2. `Home` link click -> Nagivat to `/`
3. `Error` button click -> show error.
4. Browser back -> Nagivat to `/counter` and show page fine

Behavior of my code. (Code sample BlazorApp2)

1. `Counter` link click -> Nagivat to `/counter`
2. `Home` link click -> Nagivat to `/`
3. `Error` button click -> show error.
4. Browser back -> Nagivat to `/counter` but the error message is still displayed because the exception has not been cleared

## Question

I want to display the previous screen when I move to the browser back after an error occurs.
To do this, I want to call ErrorBoundary.Recover() to clear the exception, but I don't know where to call it.

Normally, when placing an ErrorBoundary in a layout, the following statement is used.

#### MainLayout.razor

```razor
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#error-boundaries
...
<ErrorBoundary @ref="errorBoundary">
    @Body
</ErrorBoundary>

...

@code {
    private ErrorBoundary? errorBoundary;

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        errorBoundary?.Recover();
    }
}
```

I did something similar to this with App.razor as follows.

#### App.razor

```razor
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <ErrorBoundary @ref="errorBoundary">
            <ChildContent>
...
            </ChildContent>
            <ErrorContent>
                <CascadingValue Value="errorBoundary">
                    <LayoutView Layout="typeof(ErrorLayout)">
                        <Error500 Exception="@context" />
                    </LayoutView>
                </CascadingValue>
            </ErrorContent>
        </ErrorBoundary>
    </Found>
...
</Router>

@code {
    private ErrorBoundary? errorBoundary;

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        // Not called when navigation or browser back
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("**** OnParametersSet App ****");
        //errorBoundary?.Recover();
    }
}
```

However, OnParametersSet() of App.razor is not called at browser back or navigation.

If I place an ErrorBoundary in App.razor, where should I call ErrorBoundary.Recover()?

## Other things I tried 1

If the following is done, the error screen cannot be displayed because the exception information is cleared.

- Make ErrorBoundary a parameter of the error display component
- Call Recovery() in OnParametersSet() of the error display component

#### App.razor

```razor
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <ErrorBoundary @ref="errorBoundary">
            <ChildContent>
...
            </ChildContent>
            <ErrorContent>
                <LayoutView Layout="typeof(ErrorLayout)">
                    <Error500 Exception="@context" ErrorBoundary="errorBoundary"/>
                </LayoutView>
            </ErrorContent>
        </ErrorBoundary>
    </Found>
...
</Router>

@code {
    private ErrorBoundary? errorBoundary;
}
```

#### Error500.razor

```razor
<PageTitle>Server Error</PageTitle>

<h1>Server Error</h1>

<pre>@Exception?.ToString()</pre>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Exception? Exception { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public ErrorBoundary? ErrorBoundary { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        ErrorBoundary?.Recover();
    }
}
```

## Other things I tried 2

I tried to use CascadingValue to pass ErrorBoundary to ErrorLayout and call Recover() in ErrorLayout.OnParameterSet().
The error screen cannot be displayed because the exception information is cleared

#### App.razor

```razor
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <ErrorBoundary @ref="errorBoundary">
            <ChildContent>
...
            </ChildContent>
            <ErrorContent>
                <CascadingValue Value="errorBoundary">
                    <LayoutView Layout="typeof(ErrorLayout)">
                        <Error500 Exception="@context" />
                    </LayoutView>
                </CascadingValue>
            </ErrorContent>
        </ErrorBoundary>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
...
    </NotFound>
</Router>

@code {
    private ErrorBoundary? errorBoundary;
}
```

#### ErrorLayout.razor

```razor
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<PageTitle>BlazorApp2</PageTitle>

@Body

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public ErrorBoundary? ErrorBoundary { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        ErrorBoundary?.Recover();
    }
}
```

## Code sample

The code used to check is placed below.
https://github.com/usausa/question-blazor-errorhandle

Completed code sample of what I want to do.
https://github.com/usausa/Example-Net-Blazor/tree/main/ErrorHandleExample

Comment: I Check the code you provided and find that you add `RecoverRequest="() => errorBoundary?.Recover()"` in `<Error500 Exception="@context" />`, it works fine.

Comment: I do not want to clear it manually with RecoverRequest but automatically like when I call Recover() with OnParametersSet() when the ErrorBoundary is in the Layout.

Comment: I would like to be able to browser back to the previous page without any explicit action.

Comment: you want to `errorBoundary?.Recover()` in call back method in App.razor right?

Comment: I added Expected Behavior to the question.
My question is when should I call errorBoundary?.Recover() to be able to do Expected Behavior.

Comment: I am afraid you can't, [EventCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0) can't call [OnParametersSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0) method in parent component.

Comment: What I would most like to do is use a different layout in case of errors.
If I want to do this, should I place the ErrorBoundary as the root element in the MainLayout and change the layout within it, instead of having a separate ErrorLayout and placing the ErrorBoundary in App.razor?

Comment: Generally, we would set ErrorBoundary in MainLayout.

Answer (score 0):

From your Expected Behavior, When you click the `Recovery` button, You want to Nagivat to `/counter` page and use `OnParametersSet()` method to Recover the exception. Because `EventCallback` can't call `OnParametersSet()` method in parent component, You can try to NavigateTo to  `/counter` directly, Then project will call `OnParameterSet()` method to Recover Exception.

**Error500.razor**

```
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager
<PageTitle>Server Error</PageTitle>

<h1>Server Error</h1>

<pre>@Exception?.ToString()</pre>

<button @onclick="ErrorRecover">Recovery</button>



@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Exception? Exception { get; set; }
    

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<MouseEventArgs> RecoverRequest { get; set; }

    private void ErrorRecover()
    {
        _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/counter");
    }
}
```

**MainLayout**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<PageTitle>BlazorApp2</PageTitle>

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>
        <article class="content px-4">
            <ErrorBoundary @ref="_errorBoundary">
                <ChildContent >
                    @Body
               </ChildContent>
                <ErrorContent >
                    <LayoutView Layout="typeof(ErrorLayout)">
                        <Error500 Exception="@context" />
                    </LayoutView>
                </ErrorContent>
            </ErrorBoundary>
        </article>
    </main>
</div>

@code 
{
    private ErrorBoundary? _errorBoundary;
    
    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        _errorBoundary?.Recover();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this content specialized for the /counter page and can't support browser back?

Comment: Added sample BlazorApp3 with ErrorBoundary placed in the root element of MainLayout to the code sample.
With this method, when using multiple layouts depending on the page, the same mechanism is required for all layouts, but I will put up with that.